# Drawable in ViewModel with MVVM concept

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-drawable, android-architecture-components

I confused with MVVM concept that ViewModel should not reference View.
In my usecase , I have to use Databinding and wrapping the Drawable by LiveData and observe its value in xml view.

Base on suggestion from Android I implemented as below
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

> If the ViewModel needs the Application context, for example to find a
>   system service, it can extend the AndroidViewModel class and have a
>   constructor that receives the Application in the constructor, since
>   Application class extends Context.

MyViewModel.kt

```
class MyViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application){  
  private val _showIcon = MutableLiveData<Drawable>  
  val showIcon: LiveData<Drawable>  
    get() = _showIcon

  fun applyChanged(){
     if(condition){
       _showIcon.value = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getApplication(),R.drawable.icon1)
     }else{
       _showIcon.value = null
     }
  }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
   android:drawableTop="@{viewModel.showIcon}"
```

Question:
This approach is OK with MVVM concept ? Is there anything I have to do with context inside ViewModel to prevent leak memory problem?
Or any potential problem in my code ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: What if you make **BindingAdapter** for your drawable loading. In such a way, you can prevent memory leaks for storing context in `ViewModel`.

Comment: How to make BindingAdapter in my case ?

Comment: Please refer here : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#custom-logic, let me know if problem persist.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I already tried and it worked ! Thank you. 
But it's not my purpose, I am confused about my approach that has potential problem or it against MVVM concept ???

Comment: @JeelVankhede 
As far as I know, ViewModel **should not** refer Activity context because viewModel and Activity's lifecycle  is difference. 
But Application's context is OK because Application and ViewModel is same lifecycle. Is that correct ?

Comment: By the way, I accepted your reply !!!
It helps my code more clear! Thank

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any need to use databinding or view models for what you want to do. Just refer the drawable directly in xml file. If it is null, it won't be there. This is valid because you are getting the image resource from your own resources. If you were supposed to get any drawable from server or local database your approach would make sense.

Comment: Sure ! I know what you mean. However since Android Architecture Component released, we decided to apply MVVM in my project so we have to follow and keep the decision!  I also agree with you that it can be done with very simple approach. Anyway, follow ACC Android is better than anything.

Comment: From what I know and read from your link, I don't think that approach is what they advise in ACC. I can't find it anywhere... Like Google embassadors said in droidCon  18' London, "You can do it, but that's not a good reason why you should do it".

Comment: Thank you for the reply !
The reason I want to do that is all of logic should be handled in ViewModel. The Activity view just only see and show the state. Basically, I want ViewModel will control and return exactly Drawable for View then view just show it only . In order to get drawable in ViewModel, viewModel has to refer to Context . So my question is that there any potential problem with this approach.